# How to close form

Tags: c#, winforms, button, formclosing

Ok, so a Windows Forms class, WindowSettings, and the form has a "Cancel"-button. When the user clicks the button, the dialog DialogSettingsCancel will pop-up up and ask the user if he is sure he wants to perform the action. The dialog has 2 buttons, a "Yes"-button and a "No"-button. If the user clicks the "Yes"-button, I want both DialogSettingsCancel and WindowSettings to be closed.

My button_Click event handler in DialogSettingsCancel:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Code to trigger when the "Yes"-button is pressed.
    WindowSettings settings = new WindowSettings();
    this.Close();
    settings.Close();
}
```

When I run my application, and go to the settings form, and click the "Cancel"-button, and then click the "Yes"-button, only DialogSettingsCancel closes without closing WindowSettings.

Why won't it work?

I've also tried changing

```
this.Close();
settings.Close();
```

to

```
settings.Close();
this.Close();
```

But still the same result.

Comment: your "settings" are never shown to be closed in the first place, you probably are looking for some other instance

Comment: This happens because you are closing the `Window` that is handling the click event before you close the other `Window`. This isn't a Form class this is a `Window` class huge difference. Furthermore settings is not equal to the instance of WindowSettings its equal to some entirely different instance.  Use the VS debugger.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need the actual instance of the `WindowSettings` that's open, not a new one.

Currently, you are creating a new instance of `WindowSettings` and calling `Close` on that. That doesn't do anything because that new instance never has been shown.

Instead, when showing `DialogSettingsCancel` set the current instance of `WindowSettings` as the parent.

Something like this:

In `WindowSettings`:

```
private void showDialogSettings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dialogSettingsCancel = new DialogSettingsCancel();
    dialogSettingsCancel.OwningWindowSettings = this;
    dialogSettingsCancel.Show();
}
```

In `DialogSettingsCancel`:

```
public WindowSettings OwningWindowSettings { get; set; }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
    if(OwningWindowSettings != null)
        OwningWindowSettings.Close();
}
```

This approach takes into account, that a `DialogSettingsCancel` could potentially be opened without a `WindowsSettings` as parent.

If the two are always connected, you should instead use a constructor parameter:

In `WindowSettings`:

```
private void showDialogSettings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dialogSettingsCancel = new DialogSettingsCancel(this);
    dialogSettingsCancel.Show();
}
```

In `DialogSettingsCancel`:

```
WindowSettings _owningWindowSettings;

public DialogSettingsCancel(WindowSettings owningWindowSettings)
{
    if(owningWindowSettings == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("owningWindowSettings");

    _owningWindowSettings = owningWindowSettings;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
    _owningWindowSettings.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also close the application:

```
Application.Exit();
```

It will end the processes.

Answer (score 6):

```
new WindowSettings();
```

You just closed a brand new instance of the form that wasn't visible in the first place.

You need to close the *original* instance of the form by accepting it as a constructor parameter and storing it in a field.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use the DialogResult method to close the form?

```
if(DialogSettingsCancel.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Yes)
{
     //this will close the form but will keep application open if your 
     //application type is "console" in the properties of the project
     this.Close();
}
```

For this to work however you will need to do it inside your "WindowSettings" form while you call the DialogSettingsCancel form.  Much the same way you would call the OpenFileDialog, or any other Dialog form.

Answer (score 2):

Your closing your instance of the settings window right after you create it. You need to display the settings window first then wait for a dialog result. If it comes back as canceled then close the window. For Example:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Settings newSettingsWindow = new Settings();

    if (newSettingsWindow.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
    {
        newSettingsWindow.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are different methods to open or close winform.
Form.Close() is one method in closing a winform.

When 'Form.Close()' execute , all resources created in that form are destroyed.
Resources means control and all its child controls (labels , buttons) , forms etc.

Some other methods to close winform

1. Form.Hide()
2. Application.Exit()

Some methods to Open/Start a form

1. Form.Show()
2. Form.ShowDialog()
3. Form.TopMost()

All of them act differently , Explore them !

Answer (score 0):

send the **WindowSettings** as the parameter of the constructor of the **DialogSettingsCancel** and then on the **button1_Click** when yes is pressed call the close method of both of them.

```
public class DialogSettingsCancel
{
    WindowSettings parent;

    public DialogSettingsCancel(WindowSettings settings)
    {
        this.parent = settings;        
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Code to trigger when the "Yes"-button is pressed.
        this.parent.Close();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for example, if you want to close a windows form when an action is performed there are two methods to do it

1.To close it directly

```
Form1 f=new Form1();
f.close(); //u can use below comment also
//this.close();
```

2.We can also hide form without closing it

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 f1 = new Form1();
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        int flag = 0;
        string u, p;
        u = textBox1.Text;
        p = textBox2.Text;
        if(u=="username" && p=="pasword")
        {
            flag = 1;
        }
        else
        {
          MessageBox.Show("enter correct details");
        }
        if(flag==1)
        {
            f2.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }

    }
```