# can not close form by form.close() in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to open one form through another form by means of a button and close current form. i found how to do that but i tried my way and could not do that.
why this code does not work

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            Advise1 form = new Advise1();
            form.Show();
            this.Close();


    }
```

I know how to solve my problem but i want to know why close() method do not close() first form. when i try this way two form are open after click on button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# open a new form then close the current form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548746/c-sharp-open-a-new-form-then-close-the-current-form)

Comment: @Sachin yes i searched but i did not understand why this way does not work :/

Comment: define *"does not work"*

Comment: @Cid i saw this post but did not answer my question.

Comment: @Cid does not accept.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to close form in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381705/how-to-close-form-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @Cid Corrected it, that was not problem, just a mistake in typing. :))

Comment: I know how to solve my problem but i want to know why close() method do not close() first form.

Comment: Use this.Dispose(); or this.Close(); 
if you are calling function from the same class.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what your problem or error was, but the answer is likely in your main program's entry point - usually in program.cs:

```cs
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        Application.Run(form1);
    }
}
```

`Application.Run(form1);` is basically saying "this instance of Form1 is my application, keep running until this form closes."

When you invoke `this.Close();` you are closing your Form1 instance which is basically closing your whole application down.

Comment: I tried this and receive error "'SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault must be called before the first IWin32Window object is created in the application.'"

Comment: I know how to solve my problem but i want to know why close() method do not close() first form.

Comment: close() method in this way does not close whole app.